# Android How to set String array into a single textview

Tags: java, android

I'd like to try to set string array as text of the textview. How can I do that?

Below is what I've tried so far:

```
String[] word = { "Pretty", "Cool", "Weird" };

tv.setText( word.length );
```

But it's throwing some errors. I'm new to Android/Java

Comment: You are setting lenght, not the array. Tried `Arrays.toString(word);`??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`word.length` gives you length of the array, not the content. You mean to set the content to `tv`. You can use [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method: -

```
String[] word = { "Pretty", "Cool", "Weird" };

// Prints [Pretty, Cool, Weird]
tv.setText(Arrays.toString(word));   

// Prints Pretty, Cool, Weird
tv.setText(Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

Answer (score 7):

[TextView.setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) takes a `CharSequence` as the first argument so the compiler will complain if you pass in an `int` in the case of `word.length`.

Using an enhanced for-loop:

```
String[] word = { "Pretty", "Cool", "Weird" };
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s: word) {
    builder.append(s);
    builder.append(" ");
}

tv.setText(builder.toString().trim()); // .trim to remove the trailing space.
```

or since Java 8:

```
tv.setText(String.join(" ", word));
```